# How to pass an array as a argument in rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute query below but I get an error.

```
Event.where("id IN ? and event_start_date > ?",[1, 2],Time.now)
```

I get error as follows:

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (id IN 1,2 and event_start_date > '2015-03-11 04:40:43.819487')
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (id IN 1,2 and event_s...
```

Parameter value is not consider as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sank : your error gives your answer

there is syntax error in your query...

Instead of this

```
Event.where("id IN ? and event_start_date > ?",[1, 2],Time.now)
```

try this :

```
Event.where("id IN (?) and event_start_date > (?)",[1, 2],Time.now)
```

put () beside ?.

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error. I think you can make your code easier to read, which would help prevent this kind of error:

```
Event.where({ id: [1, 2], event_start_date: Time.now })
```

In this format you pass a hash to the where query with `id` and `event_start_date` as the hash keys, and `[1, 2]` (an array) and `Time.now` as the values.

This is much more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: With this solution, the query will only looks for Events with a start date of EXACTLY "now." Consider revising your answer to include the greater-than condition used in the question.

Answer (score 3):

For a combination of an array argument and a range operation, I would do this as I find it more readable:

```
Event.where(id: [1, 2]).where("event_start_date > ?", Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.where("id IN(?) AND event_start_date < (?)", [1,2,3], Time.now)
```

You're missing the `()` around the **?** mark sign.